# Error adding image when exporting excel using ClosedXML library

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am trying to use a ClosedXML.Excel XLWorkbook dll to export Excel, but when trying to use an image, I get the following error:

Cannot convert Closedxml.excel.IXLAddress to Closedxml.excel.IXLCell:

```
                var image = WS.AddPicture(imagePath)
                    .MoveTo(WS.Cell("A1").Address)
                    .Scale(1.0); // optional: resize picture
```

[image]

I do not know if something is missing to install, some version that is not compatible or I don't know what it can be, of course, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Please insert code as text, not as image. It is easier to search, copy and fix.

Answer (score 2):

The `MoveTo()` method needs a `IXLCell` as parameter, so just use

```
var image = WS.AddPicture(imagePath).MoveTo(WS.Cell("A1")).Scale(1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, with the example you gave me, the image is superimposed on the texts and the size is not adjusted